# Die Rolling Game

Tags: java

I am writing a program that returns a random number from a six sided die and also takes in a string to ask the user the amount of sides for a second dice. If the user enters the numbers 2,4,8,10,12,20,100 then the dice roles with that many sides. If the user enters a number other than that, than the second dice should role a die with six sides. Our problem is if the user enters a number other than the given values, it returns 0. We need to return a random number between 1 and 6 since it is a six sided die. Any suggestions on how to fix our code?

```
//Blueprint
public class Die{
private int numSides;
private int sideFacingUp;
public int die1;
public int die2;
public int num;


public Die()
{
    roll();
}
public Die(int number)
{
num = number;
    if(num==2||num==4||num==8|num==10||num==12||num==20||num==100)
    {
    roll2(num);
    }
    else
    {
        roll();
    }
}
public void roll()
{
    die1= (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;
}
public void roll2(int no)
{
    die2 = (int)(Math.random()*no)+1;

}
public int getDie1()
{
    //System.out.println("I m here");
    return die1;
}
public int getDie2()
{
    return die2;
}

}


//actual program
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DieTester{
public static void main(String[] args){
int num;
Die D1 = new Die();
Scanner s1 = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("The Value of the First Die:"+D1.getDie1());
System.out.println("Enter number of Die you want to create");
num = s1.nextInt();
Die D2 = new Die(num);

System.out.println("The Value of the Second Die:"+D2.getDie2());

}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: First step: In your die class get rid of die1 and die2 and create dieFace; You are thinking about this wrong. The only value you want to return is the top of the die, not two different dice. Also get rid of roll2. you don't need it. die1 and die2 becomes dieFace and only return dieFace.

Comment: In your main, the question "Enter number of Die you want to create" does not sound good here. The question should be something like: "How many sides or faces do you want the second die to have?"

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in the `getDie2()`.

When you call `roll()` you are assigning the number to `die1`.

So, if the user entered 3. It calls `roll()` and assigns random value to `die1` instead of `die2` and default value of an `int` is always `0`. That's why you are getting `0`.

Change the `getDie2()` to check for `0` value.

```
public int getDie2()
{
     if(die1 == 0) // die1 will be 0 because roll2() is called. So return die2
     {
         return die2;
     }
     else         // die2 will be 0 because roll() is called. So return die1
     {
         return die1;
     }
}
```

So to get rid of this unnecessary checks, remove `die1` and  `die2` and use only one value for the face of the die, irrespective of the die.

Like this:

```
public class Die{

private int sideFacingUp;
private int numSides;


public Die()
{
    roll();
}
public Die(int number)
{
    numSides = number;
    if(numSides==2||numSides==4||numSides==8|numSides==10||numSides==12||numSides==20||numSides==100)
    {
    roll2(numSides);
    }
    else
    {
        roll();
    }
}
public void roll()
{
    sideFacingUp= (int)(Math.random()*6)+1;
}
public void roll2(int no)
{
    sideFacingUp = (int)(Math.random()*no)+1;

}
public int getDie()
{
    //System.out.println("I m here");
    return sideFacingUp;
}

}
```

Comment: So it says i need two data fields, one that stores the number of sides on the die and another that stores which side is currently facing up. I see that you are using the side facing up data field, but what about the numSides; data field, it doesn't look like it is doing anything?

Comment: @Angie I think I forgot to delete that. It is of no use. I mean `num`. You can use `numSides` instead of `num` because it is more readable.